# intuition in definition of the dimension of a finite module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module.
Then the dimension of $M$ is defined to be the dimension of
the quotient $A/ann(M)$, where $ann(M)$ stands for the annihilator of $M$.

Question: what is the intuition behind this definition?

Comment: What meaning of finite are you using here? Finitely generated?

Comment: Yes, i will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a positively Z-graded Noetherian $k$-algebra ($k$ a field), the Krull dimension measures the rate of growth of the Hilbert function (it is asymptotically a polynomial of degree $d-1$ where $d$ is the Krull dimension). The same applies to finitely generated graded modules. The intuition here is that the Hilbert function of the module roughly grows like a scalar times the Hilbert function of $A/ann(M)$ (the scalar could be interpreted as the rank of the module if its support is irreducible) but there may be "lower-order terms" in the background, which can be ignored from the point of view of degree of order of growth.

In the non-graded, but local, case, we can reduce to a graded situation by looking at associated graded modules with respect to powers of the maximal ideal $m$ (or any $m$-primary ideal).